# Is [recovery] a meta-tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Is [recovery](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) a meta-tag and thus [worthy of being removed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)? In particular, it seems to fail the first test:

> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like `[beginner]`, `[subjective]`, and `[best-practices]`, are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[recovery](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) was, on all the questions to which it was applied, a meta tag modifying some more specific tag (e.g. [spins](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spins)). I also can't see a situation where it would work on its own, as you need to be recovering from *something*.

I have retagged the affected questions, and [recovery](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) should die out on its own within a few hours.